# Firefox not loading style immediately

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I have updated Firefox to the newest version (57.0), and now on almost every page load, the page loads without style first (so, all the links in plain HTML on the left side of the screen), and after less than 1 second, the page is rendered normally. This is very annoying. Can I somehow make Firefox behave as before, by showing the old page content (from before the page load) or a white page?

Comment: This sounds like [Firefox bug 1404468](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1404468)...